# Azure Backup offline initial backup not completing

Tags: backup, azure

We have a on-premises Windows server we are trying to get to backup to Azure. They have limited bandwidth. We started an "Offline-Backup workflow in Azure Backup." It appears that the import of the initial data was successful into the storage container, however after the import job finished, the Recovery agent has not copied the contents to the Backup Vault.

Comment: please check Recovery services vault, maybe the recovery services agent  copies the contents of the data from this account to the Recovery services vault.

Comment: Can you extend your question to share some details, such as any errors/messages you see, and the relevant aspects of your config? See https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask for some additional considerations